# Python bloom filter

Tags: python, bloom-filter

I was hoping to get some feedback on my [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) implementation using `mmh3`. [`mmh3`](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3/) is a hashing library based on the murmur hash which is a fast non-cryptographically secure hashing algorithm.

I tested it with some simple words and it seems to be working.

```python
import hashlib

import bitarray
import mmh3


def calc_optimal_hash_func(lenght_of_entries):
    m = (-lenght_of_entries * math.log(0.01)) / ((math.log(2)) ** 2)
    k = (m / lenght_of_entries) * math.log(2)

    return int(m), int(math.ceil(k))


def lookup(string, bit_array, seeds):
    for seed in range(seeds):
        result = mmh3.hash(string, seed) % len(bit_array)
        # print "seed", seed, "pos", result, "->", bit_array[result]
        if bit_array[result] == False:
            return string, "Def not in dictionary"

    return string, "Probably in here"


def load_words():
    data        = []
    word_loc    = '/usr/share/dict/words'

    with open(word_loc, 'r') as f:
        for word in f.readlines():
            data.append(word.strip())

    return data


def get_bit_array():
    words               = load_words()
    w_length            = len(words)
    array_length, seeds  = calc_optimal_hash_func(w_length)
    bit_array           = array_length * bitarray.bitarray('0')

    for word in words:
        try:
            for seed in range(seeds):
                # print "word", word, "seed", seed, "pos", result, "->", bit_array[result]
                pos = mmh3.hash(word, seed) % array_length
                bit_array[pos] = True
        except:
            pass

    return seeds, bit_array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seeds, ba = get_bit_array()
    print(lookup('badwordforsure', ba, seeds))
    print(lookup('cat', ba, seeds))
    print(lookup('hello', ba, seeds))
    print(lookup('jsalj', ba, seeds))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I'm no really into Bloom filter, so those aspects needs to be reviewed by someone else. However, there are some idiomatic stuff I would like to address in your code.

First let me mention some style issues (mostly my preferences, and not really large issues):

- *Consider specifying imports* – You are using limited parts of `bitarray` and `mmh3`, so you could consider using `from bitarray import bitarray` and `from mmh3 import hash`. However, this is based on personal preferences, and using `mmh3.hash()` does clearly indicate which hash function you're using.
- *Do you need the `hashlib` import?* – It doesn't seem like you using anything from it. Is it needed?
- *Don't use more parentheses than needed* – In `calc_optimal_hash_func()` you use a lot of parentheses. Are really all of those needed? It seems a little too much, and I'd prefer not to use that many, as it kind of clutters up the formulas to some extent. This is still more of a general advice, though.
- *Don't test for `== False`* – Use the `not` operator instead, and do `if not bit_array[result]:`. It simply make more sense.
- *Variable naming* – Naming a variable `result`, or `bit_array`, or `string` doesn't convey anything about the purpose of the variable. These and some of the other could benefit from better naming.
- *Comment on the non-obvious stuff* – It would be nice to see some comments describing what actually happens in your code. What kind of a `lookup` do you do?
- *Mostly good spacing* – Most of your code is reasonable easy to read, but I don't like the alignment at start of `get_bit_array()`. I think it would be better to use the default way of `words = load_words()` and so on.

### Code smells

In addition to the smaller style issues, there are some bigger code smells in your code which I would like to address:

- *`load_words()` hides a global constant* – It always loads `/usr/share/dict/words`, which kind of removes the need for a function. It would make a little more sense if you had `load_words(dictionary_file)`.
- *`load_words()` reads the whole file into memory* – If I'm not mistaken, part of the reason you're wanting to use a Bloom Filter is to verify membership within a really large data structure. When you load the entire thing into memory, there is no need for the filter, you'd be better off checking for membership in the array directly!
- *Why the `try...except` around the `mmh3.hash()`?* – This seems a little strange, as you `pass` the catch all the time. Does this serve some unknown purpose? If so, it should have been documented. And if not, it should be removed.
- *Consider making a class, instead of functions* – Having `get_bit_array()` return two variables, which you need to shuffle around later on, makes me think that this would better be served with a class. Imaging something like the following main section:

  ```
  bloom_filter = BloomFilter('/usr/share/dict/words')

  print(bloom_filter.lookup('badwordforsure'))
  print(bloom_filter.lookup('cat'))
  print(bloom_filter.lookup('hello'))
  print(bloom_filter.lookup('jsalj'))
  ```

  This would also expose what you're filtering towards, and it would allow for better interface and handling in general. It does seem like most of the functions are only used once, with the exception of the `lookup` function.
- *Join `load_words()` and `get_bit_array()`* – In order to avoid keeping the entire dictionary in memory, I would build the bit_array directly when reading the file. This would really ease the memory requirements of your code.

### Alternative implementation

Here is an implementation were I've taken most of these advice into account:

```
import mmh3
import bitarray
import math

class BloomFilter:
    """By building a bit array based upon a dictionary, this class
    allows for probable membership, and certain non-membership of
    any lookups within the filter."""

    def __init__(self, dictionary_file):
        """Based on the dictionary_file, builds a bit array to 
        be used for testing membership within the file for a given
        percentage, and accurate non-membership."""

        # Skip file to get number of words
        number_words = sum(1 for line in open(dictionary_file))

        # Initialize some variables
        self.calc_optimal_hash(number_words)
        self.bit_array = self.array_length * bitarray.bitarray('0')

        # Reread file, and build bit array 
        with (open(dictionary_file, 'r')) as dict_file:
            for word in dict_file.readlines():
                for seed in range(self.seed_count):
                    hashIndex = mmh3.hash(word, seed) % self.array_length
                    self.bit_array[hashIndex] = True


    def calc_optimal_hash(self, number_words):
        """Calculate array_length and seed_count."""

        # If I'm mistaken in precedence, re-add parentheses :-)
        m = -number_words * math.log(0.01) / math.log(2) ** 2
        k = m / number_words * math.log(2)

        self.array_length = int(m)
        self.seed_count = int(math.ceil(k))


    def probable_member(self, word):
        """Test whether word probably is in the dictionary, or
        are surely not in the dictionary."""

        for seed in range(self.seed_count):
            candidateHash = mmh3.hash(word, seed) % self.array_length
            if not self.bit_array[candidateHash]:
                return False

        return True


    def lookup(self, word):
        """Test whether word probably is in the dictionary, or
        are surely not in the dictionary."""

        if self.probable_member(word):
            return '"{}" is most likely in dictionary'.format(word)
        else:
            return '"{}" is not in dictionary'.format(word)


def main():

   bloom_filter = BloomFilter('/usr/share/dict/words')

   print(bloom_filter.lookup('badwordforsure'))
   print(bloom_filter.lookup('cat'))
   print(bloom_filter.lookup('hello'))
   print(bloom_filter.lookup('jsalj'))

main()
```

If you're using Python 2.x, I would also consider using `xrange(seed_count)` if `seed_count` is somewhat large, to avoid creating that array in-memory. This is better handled by default in Python3.

In the suggested code I read the file twice in order to get the number of words. This would in a lot of cases be better than reading the entire file into memory, and reading is usually cheap. If not an exact number of words is needed, I would estimate this number by taking the file size, and dividing by the average word length.

Finally, I've also created the `probable_member()` to return a boolean regarding the membership, as this allows for other uses rather than just presenting a text.

Hopefully you'll see the benefit of packaging this into a class. This implementation should allow for a much smaller memory footprint, and it would also easier allow for multiple filter to be used in parallel by instantiating multiple filter simultaneously if that should be wanted.

Comment: As for loading the entire dictionary into memory - I wouldn't actually do that in a real case. I would just generate the bitfield array and pass that to the client side to check for set membership. I should pickle the value and modify the code to show how the client would use it.

Comment: @Bobloblawlawblogs, we can only review what we see. :-) So if you wouldn't do it in real code, you should have presented that method here as well.